# Use name Geeta in place of Geeta Geeta

Tags: gmail

My name is Geeta. As first and last name is required to be filled in while creating a Gmail account, I typed Geeta Geeta as first and last name respectively. Please tell me how I can amend my name as Geeta, as my name is Geeta and not Geeta Geeta.

Comment: And you don't have a last name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to http://plus.google.com with your credentials, and then go to your *Profile settings*.

In the top of the Profile settings page you can see your profile image and name. Place the mouse cursor on your name, and the message *Click to edit your name* appears, so click it.